# Pandas - Change the default date format when creating a dataframe from CSVs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that loops through a folder of CSVs, reads them, removes any empty rows (they all have 'empty' rows that Pandas reads as NaN) and appends them to a master dataframe. It then writes the dataframe to a new CSV. This is all working as expected:

```
    if pl.Path(file).suffix == '.csv':
        fullPath = os.path.join(sourceLoc, file)
        print(file)
        initDF = pd.read_csv(fullPath)
        cleanDF = initDF.dropna(subset=['Name'])
        masterDF = masterDF.append(cleanDF)
masterDF.to_csv(destLoc, index=False)
```

My only issue is the input dates are displayed like this `25/05/21` but the output dates end up formatted like this `05/25/21`. As I'm in the UK and using a UK version of Excel to analyse the output, it's confusing all my functions.

The only solutions I've found so far are to reformat the date columns individually or style them, which to my understanding only affects how they look in Jupyter and not in the actual data. As there are multiple date columns in the source data files I'd rather not have to reformat them all individually.

Is there any way of defining the date format when first creating the dataframe, or reformatting every date column once the dataframe is filled?

Comment: You can use strftime to cast dates to strings in the format of your chosing

Comment: You can always pass `date_format` to [pandas.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). However make sure the problem is with format written to csv, not with excel when read/import csv.

Comment: @PatrykKowalski How would I apply strftime to all the date columns at once, without casting each column individually?

Comment: How many date columns do you have that this is an issue? You can use `select_dtypes` and format in a loop

Comment: @PatrykKowalski I have 9 date columns. I'm not sure how to write a loop that would format those columns. Could I just iterate through a list of column names?

Answer (score 0):

In the end this issue was caused by two different problems.

The first was Excel intermittently exporting my dates in US format despite the original format (and my Windows Region settings) being UK format. I've now added a short VBA loop in my export code to ensure those columns are formatted correctly every time the data is exported.

The second was the CSV date being imported with incorrect dtypes. I suspect this was again the fault of Excel (2010 is problematic) but I'm unsure. I'm now correcting this with an `astype()` method.

The end result is my dates are now imported into Pandas in the correct format and outputted to a new CSV in the correct format too.